# Modifying a database doesn't need ALTER permission

Tags: mysql, database, mariadb

I've got a little problem with my database permissions. I created a user with literally no rights to test a database class I'm writing on my local machine. So now if I try to change the charset on an existing database via 'ALTER DATABASE' I just get an empty result and the character set is changed. No error for missing permissions. However, if I try the same thing on a not existing database I get as expected the missing permission error. I also tried the same thing for the 'CREATE DATABASE' statement and for this, it gives me an error for my user. So what I'm doing wrong? Did anyone get a solution for this?

Database system:

- Server: 127.0.0.1 via TCP/IP
- Server-Typ: MariaDB
- Server-Verbindung: SSL wird nicht verwendet
- Dokumentation Server-Version: 10.4.17-MariaDB - mariadb.org binary distribution
- Protokoll-Version: 10

Connection via PHP file with mysqli.

Comment: What is the output of `SHOW GRANTS;` ?   (see: [mysql-docs](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/show-grants.html) and/or [mariadb-docs](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/show-grants/))

Comment: Array
(
    [Grants for norights@localhost] => GRANT USAGE ON *.* TO `norights`@`localhost`
)

I also tried to give the user only SELECT permission before, also without luck.

Answer (score 0):

If you create a user with no permissions and you still get access then
IT IS the database which allows ALL users to apply changes.
Check your database configuratio.
You can also give us further data to help you configure it.

Comment: But why my user can't create a database as expected then. Can the database just allow all users only this one function? Where can I check the database configurations? Can't find something related in the my.ini.

Comment: Probably the "all_users" user has permissions to modify one thing but not the other. Im a bit blind to help you without being able to see what can or cant do each user. 
Default permissions are usually pretty loose for SOME actions (but not all)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is not reproducable:

```
MariaDB [(none)]> select @@version;
+--------------------+
| @@version          |
+--------------------+
| 10.5.8-MariaDB-log |
+--------------------+
1 row in set (0.000 sec)

MariaDB [(none)]> show grants;
+--------------------------------------+
| Grants for @localhost                |
+--------------------------------------+
| GRANT USAGE ON *.* TO ``@`localhost` |
+--------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.000 sec)

MariaDB [(none)]> create database ThisOneDoesNotExistYet;
ERROR 1044 (42000): Access denied for user ''@'localhost' to database 'ThisOneDoesNotExistYet'
MariaDB [(none)]>
```